# Using output of a function as input for the same function for each new iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I am converting multiple docx files to a dataframe file. The code works for one document and this leads to the following structure:

```
data = {'Index Title': ['Index first title', 'Index second title'], 'Title': ['title first article, 'title second article'], 'Sources': ['source of first article', 'source of second article']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

The structure is the result from a function:

```
def func_convert_updates(filename):
    path = os.chdir('C:/Users/docxfiles')
    regex = '\xc2\xb7'
    with open(filename, "rb") as docx_file:
        result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file)
        text = result.value # The raw text
        text2=re.sub(u'[|•●]', " ", text, count= 0) 
        with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as text_file:
            text_file.write(text2)

    #followed by many lines of code, omitted here, to create a dataframe

    x = 0
    
    index = [idx for idx, s in enumerate(article_titles) if '<h2>' in s][0]
    for i, row in enumerate(article_titles):       
        if i < index:
            x = x+1 
            index_article.append(x)
        else:
            if ('empty' in row) or ('<h2>' in row):
                x = x+1 
                index_article.append(x)
            else:
                index_article.append(x)

    return df_titles, index_article
```

And then I want to analyse multiple docx files so therefore I wrote the following code:

```
list_january= [f for f in listdir('C:/Users/january2021') if isfile(join('C:/Users/january2021', f))]
df_titles = pd.concat([func_convert_updates(element) for element in list_news_january], ignore_index=True)
```

Now the problem is as follows. Each document has multiple articles (so several article titles). I want to  create a dateframe based on multiple documents where each article gets a number. With the following code, I create an index number for each article of each document:

This works fine, as each article gets a number assigned to it. But the problem is that for each new document, it starts again at x = 0. Somehow, I need to get to get the index_article as output and using this value as input for each new iteration. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be to fall back to a for loop, instead of a list comprehension:

```
df_titles_list = []
index_article = 0
for element in list_news_january:
  index_article = func_convert_updates(element, index_article)

df_titles = pd.concat(df_titles_list, ignore_index=True)
```